# I can't find build in prepare for submission page in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, mobile-application

I uploaded the binary file successfully to iTunes Connect from Xcode but in build section it asks me to download Xcode or Application Loader.

[image]

How can fix this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't received any emails from Apple about errors in your binary, than the build should upload to the iTunes and the '+' button should appear on the right from the 'Build' article after a while (usually after 10-20 minutes, but once I was waiting for 4-5 hours).

If waiting period is more than 20 min, try to resend your binary from the Xcode. The binary processing depends on the Apple's servers, so it may be lagged sometimes.

Comment: No need to post an answer to a duplicate question.

Comment: I fixed issue .. In xcode version 8 the Push notification by default is disable just I enabled the push notification the problem is fixed